# POST-ing on two php scripts.

Tags: javascript, php, database, post

I am trying to post the values of a form to two databases. 
One of them is local, one is not. It's like a "backup" for the client.

My problem now is that I have to use the "POST" method and pass the values to two different scripts. I have no idea how i can do that. My server does not support curl

This is what i am using :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
<table cellspacing='0' onkeydown='return editingKeydown(event);'>
<tr><th>first_name<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='first_name' name='first_name'>
<tr><th>last_name<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='last_name' name='last_name'>
<tr><th>company<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='company' name='company'>
<tr><th>phone<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='phone' name='phone'>
<tr><th>email<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='email' name='email'>
<tr><th>zip<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='zip' name='zip'>
<tr><th>street<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='street' name='street'>
<tr><th>city<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='city' name='city'>
<tr><th>state<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='state' name='state'>
<tr><th>country<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='country' name='country'>
<tr><th>reasons<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='300' size='40' id='reasons' name='reasons'>
<tr><th>notes<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='300' size='40' name='notes' id='notes'>
<tr><th>callback<td class='function'>*<td><input value='' maxlength='100' size='40' id='callback' name='callback'>
</table>
<p>
<input type='submit' value='Salvează' onclick='javascript: return SubmitForm()'>


</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function SubmitForm()
{
    if(document.forms['form'].onsubmit())
    {
        document.forms['form'].action='http://www.example.com/script1.php';
        document.forms['form'].submit();

        document.forms['form'].action='preproc.php';
        document.forms['form'].submit();
    }
    return true;
}



</script>
```

This is not working for me. Do you know of any way I can do this? Even alternatives...

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Taking backup of the database periodically can be easily done by server application. Is there any other specific reason  for doing this.

Comment: I will choose to do database replication or periodic dump (case dependance) rather than this. What will you do if one of the post fails? There will be a mismatch.

Comment: The client required me to use the "post" method for this. I would have gone for backup approach also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery.Deferred();` (https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

This way your requests will be sent at the same time, which is faster:

```
$( "#some-form" ).on( "submit", function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formOneDeferred = $.post({ ... }),
        formTwoDeferred = $.post({ ... });

    /**
     * Handler will only be triggered if and when both submits succeed
     */
    $.when( formOneDeferred, formTwoDeferred, function( firstSubmitResults, secondSubmitResults ) {
        console.log('Process submit results', firstSubmitResults, secondSubmitResults );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test it and come back with a reply on how and if it helped me. / I've read that some browsers discard one of the submits and only a couple do submit both, so this might be just what I need. Again, thank you for your comment.